# Using node.js and socket.io to broadcast every second

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am currently working on an auction script using node.js and socket.io.
The site will have 500-1000 logged in users viewing a single page during the auction. Only one item will be on sale at any one time, similar to a real auction held in an auction house.

I will be broadcasting a countdown timer to all of the signed in users from the server to the client. On the server side I will be using setInterval() of 1 second to countdown to the auction end time. Apart from this the only other message being sent across will be the current bid being passed from a single client to the server then broadcast to all.
Will this be a reliable way to do this? And will it be able to handle the usage on the server?

If not is there a way which would be better?

Thanks Shane

Comment: it would be much better to tell the client how many ms until the auction ends and let them count it down than sending out thousands of repeating packets. you can even sneak a timestamp into the price packet to re-sync all clients occasionally, in case windows updates the clock slightly during an auction.

Comment: I also like this approach, as it means the timer can be updated within the last 10 seconds of the auction to a new time. I.e If a new bid comes in at 5 seconds the timer can be reset to 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For timer value, keep updating your local timer per second on server side itself. Whenever any user comes in, give him this value and also total value of timer. Then client will start their own timers locally as per comment by `dandavis`, but keep some interval like 15 or 10 seconds on server side on which server will broadcast the current timer value so that client will sync accordingly.

In short, server will broadcast every after 10(n:you decide) seconds but it will be updating timer variable per second locally. Whenever client comes in, it will get total timer value and current timer value.

Rest functionality of broadcasting the current bid can be done in normal way.

Comment: Thanks for the response, This makes sense keeps the server from having to run every second and send out 500 packets per second if 500 users online.

Comment: Hi Shane, I'm also working on the auction script using node.js + socket.io. Already site was developed by using PHP,MySQL. I need to know how to braodcast countdown timer all auctions,but currently only one auction get sold. I'm already implemented the node+socket.io with website but above 500 users visiting the site means timer was not loading and server not responding.You have mentioned that **setinterval** was used me also applied same also every second we broadcast the data to clients how do you get the auction related data's like time,price etc. Could pls help me to sort out the problem.